# Jquery stop countdown when other function is run

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to make a countdown timer which runs a function, but also have a manual overide with button press:

The timer works fine:

HTML

```
<button class="countdown" onclick="refresh()">•</button>
```

JS

```
 // COUNTDOWN TIMER
 $(function() {
   var start = "1:00";
   var interval = setInterval(function() {
     var timer = start.split(':');
     var minutes = parseInt(timer[0], 10);
     var seconds = parseInt(timer[1], 10);
     --seconds;
     minutes = (seconds < 0) ? --minutes : minutes;
     if (minutes < 0) {
       clearInterval(interval);
       refresh();
     } else {
       seconds = (seconds < 0) ? 59 : seconds;
       seconds = (seconds < 10) ? '0' + seconds : seconds;
       $('.countdown').html(minutes + ':' + seconds);
       start = minutes + ':' + seconds;
     }
   }, 1000);
 });

// MY REFRESH FUNCTION
function refresh() {
   alert("Alert");
   $('.countdown').html("Loading");
 }
```

What I am struggling with is, when I click the manual overide button to run the refresh function, the timer still continues to count down (as in, loading is replaced with the countdown timer). What clicking the button should do is stop the countdown function running.

Can anyone help me with how this should be done?

Comment: `clearInterval` method need to call inside refresh function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var interval = null;

// COUNTDOWN TIMER
$(function() {
  var start = "1:00";
  interval = setInterval(function() {
  var timer = start.split(':');
    var minutes = parseInt(timer[0], 10);
    var seconds = parseInt(timer[1], 10);
    --seconds;
    minutes = (seconds < 0) ? --minutes : minutes;
    if (minutes < 0) {
       clearInterval(interval);
       refresh();
    } else {
       seconds = (seconds < 0) ? 59 : seconds;
       seconds = (seconds < 10) ? '0' + seconds : seconds;
       $('.countdown').html(minutes + ':' + seconds);
       start = minutes + ':' + seconds;
    }
  }, 1000);
});

// MY REFRESH FUNCTION
function refresh() {
  alert("Alert");
  $('.countdown').html("Loading");
}

$('.countdown').click(function() {
  clearInterval(interval);
});
```